# react-pro-sidebar v1.0.0 with react-router-dom v6.16.0: How to make active SubMenu when route changes on clicking MenuItems?

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom, sidebar, react-sidebar

I just created a simple sidemenu with 3 submenus and their menuitems, but the thing I want to solve is, when I click on a MenuItem and the route changes all Submenu dropdowns get closes, so its not clear for the users on which page are they, It should be active and opened which the user clicked.

**And I using react-pro-sidebar version 1.0.0 with react-router-dom version 6.16.0**

So how to achieve that, here is my code:-

SideMenu.js

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from "react-pro-sidebar";
import classes from "./MainLayout.module.css";    
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function SidebarMenu() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [openSubMenu, setOpenSubMenu] = useState(null);
  const [path, setPath] = useState(location.pathname);

  const routeMenuKeys = {
    "/users": "home",
    "/companies": "home",
    "/document-category": "document",
    "/document-type": "document",
    "/document-master": "document",
    "/file-category": "document",
    "/file-master": "document",
    "/file-location": "document",
    "/uploads": "document",
    "/task-category": "task",
    "/tasks": "task",
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentRoute = path;
    const submenuKey = routeMenuKeys[currentRoute] || null;
    setOpenSubMenu(submenuKey);
  }, [path]);

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar
        rootStyles={{
          minWidth: "100%",
          width: "100%",
          // backgroundColor: "transparent",
        }}
        className={classes.sidebar_dropmenu}
      >
        <Menu
          menuItemStyles={{
            button: {
              [`&:hover`]: {
                backgroundColor: "#d6d6d6",
              },
            },
          }}
        >
          <SubMenu label={`Home`}}>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "home"}
            >
              Dashboard
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/users" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "home"}
            >
              Users
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/companies" />}

              open={openSubMenu === "home"}
            >
              Companies
            </MenuItem>
          </SubMenu>
          <SubMenu label={`Document Management`}>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/document-category" />}

              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              Document Category
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/document-type" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              Document Type
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/document-master" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              Document Master
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/file-category" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              File Category
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/file-master" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              File Master
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/file-location" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              File Location
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/uploads" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "document"}
            >
              Uploads
            </MenuItem>
          </SubMenu>
          <SubMenu label={`Task Management`}>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/task-category" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "task"}
            >
              Task Category
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem
              component={<Link to="/tasks" />}
              open={openSubMenu === "task"}
            >
              Tasks
            </MenuItem>
          </SubMenu>
        </Menu>
      </Sidebar>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here how it looks: -

[image]